# ROSBAG with points cloud

Tags: rosbag, ros-kinetic, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I have a rosbag file contain images and measurement point list. I have already extracted images.

There is a topic of type `datatypes/scan_point_list_2202`

And I have no idea from where to start. I need to extract point cloud. Please refer me some useful links/tutorials so that I can get an idea how to extract this information.

Thanks and Regards,
ARM

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290051/rosbag-with-points-cloud/) by [ARM](https://answers.ros.org/users/34802/arm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`datatypes/scan_point_list_2202` looks like a custom message type, the standard ROS point cloud message are `sensor_msgs/PointCloud` or `sensor_msgs/PointCloud`

If you look in the msgs folder of the package that defines this custom message you should find the definition of it.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ARM](https://answers.ros.org/users/34802/arm/) on 2018-05-02**:
I played the rosbag file and echo rostopic. Can you look at the [output file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B2YgBbHkkz7CrDZm_xCZcLHj8To4SvNt) here.